# How do I display only distinct objects in a queryset that have values in them?

Tags: python, django, templates, view, model

I have multiple objects saved in my database but I would only like to show items in my queryset that are unique and if they actually have an item saved.

## models.py

```
class Everything(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User)
    playlist = models.CharField('Playlist', max_length = 2000, null=True, blank=True)
    platform = models.CharField('Platform', max_length = 2000, null=True, blank=True)
    video = models.CharField('VideoID', max_length = 2000, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s' % (self.profile, self.playlist, self.platform, self.video)
```

## views.py

```
playlist2 = Everything.objects.filter(profile=request.user)
```

## template

```
<select name ="playlist2">
{% for item in playlist2 %}
  <option value="{{item.playlist}}">{{item.playlist}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

There doesn't have to be a playlist because null=True and blank=True.  Some of the items in playlist might also be duplicated.  How do I show only the distinct items that have values in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exclude` and `distinct` queryset functions ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/)).

However in your case it is not that simple since your `CharField` definitions allow both `NULL` (`null=True`) and empty string (`blank=True`) values. So that means you have to test for two conditions and for that you have to use `Q` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)) objects:

```
 everything = Everything.objects.exclude(Q(playlist=None) | Q(playlist='')).distinct()
```

That is exactly why Django docs do not recommend to use `null=True` for string model fields ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#null)). Here is excerpt:

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and
>   TextField unless you have an excellent reason. If a string-based field
>   has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”:
>   NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two
>   possible values for “no data;” Django convention is to use the empty
>   string, not NULL.

If you follow this conversion, then your filter lookup becomes much simpler:

```
 everything = Everything.objects.exclude(playlist=None).distinct()
```

Comment: I have 2 objects that have different values for the "video" attribute in the model but have the same "playlist" attribute (named Favorites).  How do I get only Favorites to show up once?  With the above solution, Favorites still shows up twice because they are different objects (they have different values for the other attribute).  Thanks in advance!

Comment: For that, it does not make any sense to get `Everything` objects since at that point, you are not filtering them according to a condition, but to an aggregate condition. To get unique playlist values, you can do `Everything.objects.filter(...).exclude(...).values('playlist').distinct()`

Answer (score 0):

You could just filter out all the null and blank objects.

```
playlist2 = Everything.objects.filter(playlist__isnull=False).exclude(playlist__exact='').distinct()
```

I edited the above to include handling of blanks, as noted by miki725.  There's probably no need for the `Q()` functions though.  Not that there's anything wrong with `Q()` functions, I just try to avoid them where readability could be increased.  By DeMorgan's theorem, `NOT (playlist is null OR playlist is blank)` is equivalent to `(NOT playlist is null) AND (NOT playlist is blank)`.  I prefer `filter` to `exclude`, but `exclude` is necessary for the blanks, since there's no unequal field lookup.  You could just as well `exclude` the null playlists, but what you can't do is combine the excludes into one call, unless you use Q functions, otherwise you get `NOT (playlist is null AND playlist is blank)`, which is not equivalent.

Comment: This will not work because Django will pretty much always store strings as empty strings and not NULL unless you programmatically make a string to `None` and then save a model. Refer to my answer for better explanation.